# Function for root class of numeric types

Tags: c#, oop

I need to make a formal function, that do nothing and just exists, for every numeric type in c#. Is there a root or basic class for all numeric classes to make it looks like :

```
public static class FunctionalExtensions{
 public static void AVG<NumericType>(NumericType x) where NumericType : INumeric
 {}
}
```

Or maybe there is an another way to do something like this for some list of various classes?

Found something about "Generic math" in .NET 7

Comment: What exactly is your question? How to leverage `INumber<T>` in .NET 7? Or how to solve this problem without .NET 7?

Comment: how to solve it without INumber<T>

Answer (score 3):

```cs
public static void AVG<NumericType>(NumericType x) where NumericType : INumber<NumericType>
```

(or `T` or `TNumber`, perhaps, instead of `NumericType`)

Since this looks like "average", tip:

```cs
var sum = T.Zero;
var count = T.Zero;
foreach (var value in ...)
{
    sum += value;
    count += T.One;
}
return sum / count;
```